# How to specify current directory for Docker?

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile

I'm following this part of the Docker tutorial (on a Mac): https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_four/.  I'm getting an error when I try to run the docker-whalesay image because it can't find fortunes.

I started off in the Dockerfile using `/user/games/fortunes`.  Then I changed to just `fortunes`.  Neither work.

How do I specify in the Dockerfile to use the current folder (mydockerbuild)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfile in that example does not rely on files that are present on your computer, basically, the only steps needed are;

1. Create an empty directory (you named it `mydockerbuild`)

   ```
   mkdir mydockerbuild
   ```
2. Change to that directory

   ```
   cd mydockerbuild
   ```
3. Create a Dockerfile
4. Edit the Dockerfile to look like this;

   ```
   FROM docker/whalesay:latest
   RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
   CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
   ```
5. Build the Dockerfile, and name the built image "docker-whale"

   ```
   docker build -t docker-whale .
   ```
6. Run the image you just built

   ```
   docker run --rm docker-whale
   ```

The `/usr/games/fortunes` path in the Dockerfile is referring to a path *inside the container*. In this case, the `/usr/games/fortunes` is created by the `fortune` package that it's installed by `apt-get install -y fortunes`.

Comment: Why when I try to run the image, it keeps saying "/user/games/fortunes: not found"?

Comment: Try `/usr/`, not `/user/`.

Comment: oh, good one; I see my last paragraph also has that typo (I copy/pasted it from the original question). I'll edit